# Can't get rid of this.tech.isReady is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, video.js

I'm having a little problem with the Video.JS script (combined with BigVideo.js)

Line 2511 : this.tech.isReady is null or not an object

The following happens in IE7-8 and Firefox 12.

https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/issues/210

The following thread gives the answer (I think) on how to fix the problem.

ddadick says to add the following line.

```
V.options.flash.iFrameMode = true;
```

I've tried this one but it's not meant to be working in Firefox as the condition says :

```
if (options.iFrameMode == true && !_V_.isFF) {
```

If option mode and it's not Firefox...

I've turned of the 'Firefox' validation to test, but the iframe size was 350x100. I've tried to hack the CSS a bit but it wouldn't go fullscreen.

I also tried the other alternative which instead of running `player.play()` directly, you call it with a ready function `player.ready(function() { player.play(); } );` but it didn't change anything.

I'm just looking for a way so at least it doesn't crash in Firefox or non-supported browser. If I could get full video support in this browser it would be more than great too.

Of course I could test if Firefox 12 or less, don't load the video and show poster right away but I would have hope not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same problem I was having, then it's an issue with the Webkit implementation that Qt 4 uses on OSX. It's not actually a problem with video.js itself. The solution is to upgrade to Qt 5 which uses a newer version that doesn't throw these kinds of errors when trying to play MP4 videos, for instance. See this blog post for details about the problem and solution: http://magnemg.tumblr.com/post/113251336220/how-to-solve-a-capybara-webkit-and-video-js